# Editing Node Labels - NetworkD3 Sankey Diagram

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

When hovering a node, the label and the value attached to it appears with no spacing. For example, in the screenshot here, you will see that at 6 months, there are 64 participants who are in Stage 3.

[image]

But hovering over the node it looks like "Stage 364" because there is no spacing. I am not sure how to change or fix this. The code is pasted below.

```
# Load the libraries 
library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(haven)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(writexl)
library("readxl")

Mdf<- read_sas("C:/Users/jayla/Dropbox (TFGH Central)/LEDoxy File Sharing with Brian/Mali Main Analysis/Pull 20210913/Final Datasets/mali_table2a_20210913.sas7bdat")
Mdf2 <- spread(Mdf,redcap_event_name, STAGE_ANALYSIS_LEG)
Mdf3 <- Mdf2[,c("Baseline", "6 Months", "12 Months", "24 Months")]
# removing the M18 data from Mali bc it was not collected the same way due to covid 
# - we instead want to keep whatever was in month 12 as month 18
# DO NOT REPEAT THIS FOR OTHER SITES!!!
### UPDATE ON 6/23/22 - the table 2a no longer includes the 18M data for Mali - code has been modified to account for this change. 
# Mdf4 <- Mdf3[,c("Baseline", "6 Months", "12 Months", "12 Months", "24 Months")]
# colnames(Mdf4) <- c("Baseline", "6 Months", "12 Months", "18 Months", "24 Months")
Mdf_all <- Mdf3

df_toplot <- Mdf_all

### RESTRUCTURE DATA %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
# set if want labels or not;
full_label = FALSE;

# Dealing w NAs - DON'T CHANGE ORDER OF THESE STEPS! 
# has to be in this order so if missing multiple timepoints for a subject, it goes to earliest. 
#summarizes how many are NA per column
df_toplot %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.))) 

# changes any 6M NAs to the value at baseline 
df_toplot$`6 Months` <- ifelse(is.na(df_toplot$`6 Months`), df_toplot$Baseline, df_toplot$`6 Months` )

# changes any 12M NAs to the value at 6M 
df_toplot$`12 Months` <- ifelse(is.na(df_toplot$`12 Months`), df_toplot$`6 Months`, df_toplot$`12 Months` )

# changes any 18M NAs to the value at 12M 
# df_toplot$`18 Months` <- ifelse(is.na(df_toplot$`18 Months`), df_toplot$`12 Months`, df_toplot$`18 Months` )

# changes any 24M NAs to the value at 12M
df_toplot$`24 Months` <- ifelse(is.na(df_toplot$`24 Months`), df_toplot$`12 Months`, df_toplot$`24 Months` )





# df_toplot <- filter(df_toplot,df_toplot$`Baseline`!=".")
#  df_toplot <- filter(df_toplot,df_toplot$`6 Months`!=".")
#  df_toplot <- filter(df_toplot,df_toplot$`12 Months`!=".")
#  df_toplot <- filter(df_toplot,df_toplot$`18 Months`!=".")
# df_toplot <- filter(df_toplot,df_toplot$`24 Months`!=".")

# add word "stage" to the front of every stage value
df_toplot$Baseline <- sub("^","Stage ",df_toplot$Baseline)
df_toplot$`6 Months` <- sub("^","Stage ",df_toplot$`6 Months`)
df_toplot$`12 Months` <- sub("^","Stage ",df_toplot$`12 Months`)
# df_toplot$`18 Months` <- sub("^","Stage ",df_toplot$`18 Months`)
df_toplot$`24 Months` <- sub("^","Stage ",df_toplot$`24 Months`)
# sort by stages, starting w baseline and doing all sequentially (makes final graph look better)
# df_toplot2 <- df_toplot[order()]


#   df_toplot <- desc(df_toplot, Baseline, `6 Months`, `12 Months`, `24 Months`)
df_toplot <- arrange(df_toplot, desc(Baseline), desc(`6 Months`), desc(`12 Months`), desc(`24 Months`))

#df_toplot2 <- desc(df_toplot)
# df_toplot <- arrange(df_toplot, `24 Months`,`18 Months`,`12 Months`,`6 Months`,  Baseline,  )

# Make initial links and nodes structures ------------------------------------------------
# Later we have to make a combined version of these

# Make new data structure where each row is a link 
links <-
  df_toplot %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "source") %>% # gather all columns
  mutate(column = match(column, names(df_toplot))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = column)) %>% # get target from following node in row
  ungroup()

# Add suffix labels to stages so that they're all different , and only keep source and target 
links <-
  links %>%
  mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
  mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
  select(source, target)

# Create nodes 
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))

# Remove suffix label from nodes
nodes$label <- sub('_[0-9]*$', '', nodes$name) # remove column id from node label
nodes$group <- sub('Stage ', '', nodes$label)


# add source_id and target_id
links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

# Making collective links and nodes ------------------------------------------------

# make new version of links to use for next steps 
links2 <- arrange(links,source_id,target_id)
# initialize loop
i <- 1
n <- 1
new_links <- links[1,]
new_links$source_id <- 9
new_links$value <-0

# Start loop
for (i in 1:nrow(links2))
{
  # get start and next that we are dealing with 
  start_stage = pull(links2[i,3])
  next_stage = pull(links2[i,4])

  # only start loop if not a repeat  
  if (start_stage != new_links[n,3] | next_stage !=new_links[n,4])
  {
    # calculate how many rows follow that path
    total_mask <- links2$source_id == start_stage & links2$target_id == next_stage
    total <- sum(total_mask)

    # create a new row w that info 
    new_row <- links2[i,]
    new_row$value <- total

    # put that row into new dataframe 
    if (i==1) {n=1} else {n=n+1}
    new_links[n,] <- new_row
  }   else { i = i+1   }
}

# make a new version of nodes that has the labels we want
new_nodes <- nodes

for (i in 1:nrow(nodes))
{
  # identify which node we are talking about
  my_node = nodes$name[i]

  # sum all the values of that node in new_links
  mask <- new_links$source == my_node
  node_total <- new_links$value[mask] %>% sum

  new_nodes$label[i] <- paste(nodes$label[i], node_total, sep=": ")
}

# remove the NAs in links and nodes
# from new_nodes
new_nodes <- new_nodes[!new_nodes$name=='NA_6',] 
new_nodes <- new_nodes[!new_nodes$name=='NA_5',] 


nodes <- nodes[!nodes$name=='NA_6',]
nodes <- nodes[!nodes$name=='NA_5',]


# from new_links
new_links <- new_links[ new_links$target != 'NA_6',] 
new_links <- new_links[ new_links$target != 'NA_5',] 


### MAKING PLOT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
# Setting parameters

# define colors
new_links$group <- substr(new_links$source,7,7)

# set colors to whatever you want - this scheme is lcd safe and color blind safe
#node_colors <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["0","1","2","3","4","5"]).range(["#01665e","#5ab4ac","#c7eae5","#f6e8c3","#d8b365","#8c510a"])'
node_colors <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]).range(["#cb181d","#fc9272","#a50f15","#ef3b2c","#67000d","#fc9272"])'


#Manual Edits made by Jayla outside of R to fix order of nodes and links to our desired order
# write_xlsx(new_nodes, path = "C:/Users/jayla/Downloads/Graphics/newnodesMali.xlsx")
# write_xlsx(new_links, path = "C:/Users/jayla/Downloads/Graphics/newlinksMali.xlsx")


JlinksMali <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/jayla/Downloads/Graphics/newlinksMali_06132023.xlsx", 2)
JnodesMali <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/jayla/Downloads/Graphics/newnodesMali_06132023.xlsx", 3)

# Making plot 
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(Links = JlinksMali, Nodes = JnodesMali, Source = 'source_id',
                    Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label',
                    fontSize = 16, nodeWidth=30, nodePadding = 20, 
                    height = 300, width = 900, NodeGroup = 'group', LinkGroup = 'group',
                    colourScale= node_colors, margin = list(left = 70), iterations = 0)
#If you don't want the data labels, change Nodes= nodes


#  Making Title, printing to R, and saving 
sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$h1( "    Mali - All Participants"))
#style = "text-align: center",


htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey, '
  function(el) {
    var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    var labels = ["Baseline", "6 Months", "12 Months", "24 Months"];
    cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
      d3.select(el).select("svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", d)
        .attr("y", 12)
        .text(labels[i]);
    })
  }
')
```

I have made changes to what label shows up on the Sankey Diagram. I have changed it from stating the stage and how many are in that stage, to just the stage for a cleaner appearance: "Stage 3: 64" vs. "Stage 3". The screenshot shows when all stages just say "Stage 1", "Stage 2", etc. When the labels say the stage and number of participants in that stage, such as, "Stage 3:64", then hovering over the node produces "Stage3:6464". Not sure where in the code would fix this issue or what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help. It's difficult to help in such a versatile programming language when the question is not reproducible. That's also a likely reason your question has gone a few days with no answers. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). You did a great job including your code, but most of the code here isn't really relevant to answering your question (i.e., the data manipulation to get the data ready for the plot). That tends to deter answerers, as well, where they are really looking for that *minimally reproducible* question.

All that being said, see if this helps, if it doesn't try editing your question based on the information in that web link I provided.

I don't know what's in your data, but I'm going to guess that in the data assigned to the argument `nodes`, you've got something like: `"stage 1", "stage 2"`, etc. Assuming this to be true, to change the hover content to include both the stage and the value, you can do the following:

1. create your plot object (`sn` in this following code)
2. add the values to the nodes in the plot object ('content to be '... in the code comments)
3. add the values to the hover text (the code within `htmlwidgets::onRender`)

First I'm going to show you with a *very simple* Sankey. Then I'll provide what I think you'll need based on the code in your question.

```
library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)

# creating data for example
nodes = data.frame(name = paste0("Node ", LETTERS[1:4]))

links = data.frame(source = c(0, 0, 1, 2), 
                   target = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                   value = seq(10, 40, by = 10))

# diagram for example 
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                    Source = "source", Target = "target",
                    Value = "value", NodeID = "name")
sn
sn$x$nodes$labels <- links$value    # <--- content to be added to tooltip
sn %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
    'function(el, x) {
      d3.selectAll(".node").select("title foreignObject body pre")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name + ": " + d.labels; });
    }') # note that `d.name` is derived from `nodeID = "name"` in the Sankey
        #           'd.labels` is the values added to the nodes in the Sankey object
```

Here's my new tooltip; I'm also showing here that the edges' tips are unchanged

[image] [image]

I don't know what's in your data or where the values you want to append to the stage names are, so I don't know what you need to add to your plot after you create it. You'll have to sort that out.

I'm going to call these to be appended values 'value' (as if you assigned it to `sankey$x$node$value` where `sankey` is the name of your plot object). In my example code, I used the word `labels`. The *name* isn't all that important, but you need to match the name you used in the R code to the name you use in the Javascript within `onRender`.

In your question, you're already using `onRender`. To modify your tooltips, you'll add more content to your current call.

```
htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey, '
  function(el) {
    var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(
      function(a, b){return a - b});
    var labels = ["Baseline", "6 Months", "12 Months", "24 Months"];
    cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
      d3.select(el).select("svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", d)
        .attr("y", 12)
        .text(labels[i]);
    });                          /* I have added a semi-colon here */
    d3.selectAll(".node").select("title foreignObject body pre")
      .text(function(d) { return d.label + ": " + d.value; });
    }
') # note that `d.label` is derived from `nodeID = "label"` in your Sankey
   #           'd.value` is the values added to the nodes in the Sankey object
```

If you run into any problems or have questions, let me know. I'll do my best to help. As I said, it's pretty difficult to give you a great answer when I don't have all the necessary information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the welcome, your assistance and your tips! I was able to make it work using your answer. Thanks again!